# Any working binary differ tool implements GDIFF(Generic Diff Format, NOT Graphical file difference)?

Tags: command-line-tool, binary-diff

I've seen GDIFF(Generic Diff Format) in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_encoding), and I wander is there any command line tool implements this standard. Now the best I have is [LibXDiff](http://www.xmailserver.org/xdiff-lib.html), but it's a library, I'll need some extra work to make it run.

I know when it comes to binary-differ, VCDIFF(xdelta, etc) and bsdiff would have better compression rate, but in my case I really need a straight forward one. VCDIFF copies anything before current window(if my poor English reading was right about [this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3284) article), and bsdiff's patch file format would be more complex.

**update**

Finally I found VCDIFF with xdelta3 is actually good and working, when "disable small string-matching" and "disable external decompression" is toggled, AND it has a pretty good "printdelta" command that prints very useful(for my app) information so that I don't really neet to extract VCDIFF format from the patch file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Javaxdelta](http://javaxdelta.sourceforge.net/) library implements xdelta and GDIFF patches. It can be used as command-line application like this:

```
# create patch
java -cp javaxdelta-2.0.1.jar:trove-1.0.2.jar com.nothome.delta.Delta source.file target.file patch.gdiff
# apply patch
java -cp javaxdelta-2.0.1.jar:trove-1.0.2.jar com.nothome.delta.GDiffPatcher unpatched.file patch.gdiff patched.file
```

I wrote once a [wrapper around it](https://github.com/alexkasko/delta-updater) to support directories patching (GDIFF files for directory are packed into one ZIP patch).

Comment: Thanks, though I haven't yet check your utilities, xdelta3 works fine for me now. I'll try your tool when xdelta3's "printdelta" become not sufficient :D